# Trying to change owner of mutex object in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, object, ownership

I'm trying to change the ownership of a mutex object but it seems that this code is not working, trying to set "Everyone" as owner, I get ERROR_INVALID_OWNER error code, any ideas?

```
#include <Aclapi.h>

BOOLEAN SetEveryone(HANDLE handle)
{
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY Auth = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    PSID pSID = NULL;

    if (AllocateAndInitializeSid(
        &Auth, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pSID))
    {
        if (SetSecurityInfo(
            handle,
            SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            pSID,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("success\n");
        }

        FreeSid(pSID);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE Token;
    LUID luid;
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES privs;

    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &Token);
    LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, SE_TAKE_OWNERSHIP_NAME, &luid);

    privs.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    privs.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    privs.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;

    if (AdjustTokenPrivileges(
        Token,
        FALSE,
        &privs,
        sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES),
        NULL,
        NULL))
    {
        HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, TEXT("test1"));
        SetEveryone(mutex);
    }

    CloseHandle(Token);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that changing the ownership of a mutex is unusual, and probably doesn't do what you're expecting it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily, you can only set ownership to yourself or to a group that is in your access token and has the `SE_GROUP_OWNER` flag set.

However, you can override this rule by enabling backup and restore privileges.

Comment: Thank you, I added backup and restore privileges as you said and my old code now works, I didn't find documentation about that, where I can find it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it isn't documented as far as I know.  The description in MSDN just says "this privilege causes the system to grant all write access control to any file" but it actually affects not just files but most (all?) securable objects.